# Find whether key starts with a particular string or not in an object and get its value?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have an object as:

```
let fruitSong = {'apple song':12, 'banana song': 24}

Object.keys(fruitSong).forEach(e=>{

    if(e.startsWith('apple')){

        console.log(fruitSong[e])
    }
})
```

Is there any other method where I can check whether if there is any key matching with a given string, lets say 'apple' in this case should give the value?

In this case object element are very less but in case of big object object this solution will not be feasible.

Let me know if any other questions.

Comment: You can always check for `undefined` on `myObject[myKey]`.

Comment: ```this solution will not be feasible.``` why this solution is not feasible?

Comment: Because if there are 100s or 1000s of element in object, we need to loop through each and every key, which will not be an ideal solution as per my understanding

Comment: Do you want to check the values partially or full match only for keys? The searchable string in the key is dynamic or static ex: does `apple` will change to any other word or it will be remain apple only?

Comment: *if there are 100s or 1000s of element in object, we need to loop through each and every key* - that's both true and unavoidable. *which will not be an ideal solution as per my understanding* - compared to what? If you want to check if keys start with something, this is what you can do.

Comment: Do you want all values with a key that starts with the string or just any one value that does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually save half the iteration which can work well for thousands of record at-least in this case. However if there is more data, you might need to use some Data structure to achieve the task and efficiency.

```js
const fruitSong = {'apple song':12, 'banana song': 24, 'apple song 1':12, 'banana song 1': 24, 'apple song 2':12, 'banana song 2': 24, 'apple song 3':12, 'banana song 3': 24}

const keys = Object.keys(fruitSong);

var j = keys.length -1;
var iter = 0;

for (let i = 0; i <= j;  ) {
    iter++;
    if (i == j ) {
       console.log(keys[i]);
        break;
    }

    if (j - i == 1) {
         console.log(keys[j]);
         break;
    }

    if (keys[i].includes('apple')) {console.log(keys[i]);}

    if (keys[j].includes('apple')) {console.log(keys[j]);}

    j--;
    i++
}

console.log(`Total iteration is ${iter}`);
console.log(`Total elements are ${keys.length}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would check to see if the key starts with 'apple'...

```js
let fruitSong = {'apple song':12, 'banana song': 24}

const wordToCheck = "apple"

Object.keys(fruitSong).forEach(key => key.substr(0, wordToCheck.length) == wordToCheck && console.log(fruitSong[key]))
```

EDIT: Revised my answer to exclude regex for performance.

Comment: You would need `^apple` to match only at the start. But launching a regexp engine may be inefficient for this purpose. Also, with this in mind the second snippet is not necessary.

Comment: Revised my answer